# LINQ take average of multiple fields in query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a query like the following

```
select q1, q2, q3, q4, average from results
```

I need to calculate the average of q1 thru q5 in the average column for each row.  I have the following

```
var query = from T in db.results
                        select new ResultsCustom
                        {
                            q1, q2, q3, q4
                            average = ((double)(T.q1 ?? 0.0)
                                + (double)(T.q2 ?? 0.0)
                                + (double)(T.q3 ?? 0.0)
                                + (double)(T.q4 ?? 0.0)
                                ) / 4};
```

The problem is that q1 thru q4 can be null which would throw the average off.  If they are null I don't want to include them in the average calculation. I was thinking I could decrement the count if there is a null value.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't be translatable to SQL but you could do:

```
var query = from T in db.results
            select new ResultsCustom
            {
                q1, q2, q3, q4
                average = (new double?[] { T.q1, T.q2, T.q3, T.q4 }).Average()
            };
```

since `Average()` will ignore null values.

To get the results and do the average in Linq-to-Objects do:

```
var query = (from T in db.results select new {q1, q2, q3, q4}).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => new ResultsCustom
                 {
                     r.q1, r.q2, r.q3, r.q4,
                     average = (new double?[] { r.q1, r.q2, r.q3, r.q4 }).Average()
                 }
             );
```

Comment: Should also point out that `average` will be null if all of q1-q4 are null

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating an average there. Just use the standard formula `sum / count`.

```
...
let sum = q1.GetValueOrDefault() + q2.GetValueOrDefault() + ...
let count = (q1 != null ? 1 : 0) + ...
let avg = sum / count
...
```

You probably also need to define what should happen if `count == 0`.

Comment: Count just has to be the number of values, not dependent on whether a value is null or not.

Comment: @Dennis_E in his question he suggests that a null value does not count as a value.

Comment: @Dennis_E "If they are null I don't want to include them in the average calculation" - I translate that as "take the average of all non-null values".

Comment: Agreed with @Dennis_E, otherwise he wouldn't have divided it by 4 himself

Comment: @Dennis_E is right. Count is a constant in this case.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If he does *not* want to include them, then count cannot be constant. Otherwise he'd be averaging zeros. Which he already is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
double GetAverage(T)
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    if (T.q1 != null) list.Add(T.q1);
    if (T.q2 != null) list.Add(T.q2);
    if (T.q3 != null) list.Add(T.q3);
    if (T.q4 != null) list.Add(T.q4);
    return list.Average();
}
```

Comment: I think the point is to replace the nulls with 0, so: list.Add(T.q1 ?? 0), etc (otherwise, you could just call Average() on the Enumerable itself)

Answer (score 0):

You could generalise this as follows (not tested):

```
double GetAverage(List<double> doublesList)
{
    var list = doublesList.Where(x => x != null).ToList();
    return list.Average();
}
```

which returns the average of a list of `doubles` of any length, with `nulls` ignored, separating the process from the data acquisition.